# Selenium Microsoft Login “Your browser is a bit unusual…” Message

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to do some UI testing with Selenium and NUnit in C# but need to login through Microsoft first. After entering my information with selenium, when I try to click Sign-In I get a popup saying:

"Your browser is a bit unusual... Try disabling ad blockers and other extensions, enabling javascript or using a different web browser."

My best guess is that [it is detecting that I'm using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver), but I'm not sure as I can't find anyone else with a similar message. Is this what is happening? If so, is the solution described in the link my best option or is there another way to login to Microsoft?

Here is a rough example of my code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class FileUploadTests
{
    IWebDriver webDriver;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void StartChrome()
    {
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--enable-javascript");
        options.AddArguments("--incognito");
        options.AddArgument("--profile-directory=Default");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-plugins-discovery");
        options.AddArgument("--profile-directory=Default");
        options.AddArgument(".");
        webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Login()
    {
        webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://localhost:xxxxx/");
        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginButton")).Click();
        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("i0116")).Clear();
        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("i0116")).SendKeys("username");
        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("i0116")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).Clear();
        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("password");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("submitBtn")).Click();
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void CloseTest()
    {
        webDriver.Close();
        webDriver.Dispose();
        webDriver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to bypass logging in by using [an opened browser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F-laDV9Pl8) where I logged in manually. Still not sure what was causing the original problem though.